# Table layout in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am learning php/mysql on a night course and am finding it very hard to work out how I should layout and structure my tables in my database and no matter how long I spend making notes and trying to work it out I can't.

I am trying to create a search page where a user can search for pictures by country OR by region, but obviously lots of countries will have the same region.

I am not storing the pictures in the database, just the url, but I can't work out how to join the tables together.

The furthest I have got is a countries table, with id and name columns, a region table with id and name columns, a jointable table to join the two, with country_id and region_id columns, but I can't work out how to incorporate the table with the picture urls so that they can be searched for by region or by country.

I know the php for building the pages, I am just looking for help on how to structure the database part.

Any help would be much appreciated, I have spent hours trying to work this out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can a country reside in more than one region?

Comment: hi mike, no but regions containt multiple countries

Comment: just use one table for country, and include a region (text) column. the country names/ids would be unique but the regions could be the same between different countries.

Comment: Are pictures always linked to 1 country? many countries? countries and regions? regions only? What are the possible associations between pictures and countries/regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Regions
-------
region_id
name

Countries
---------
country_id
name
region_id

Pictures
--------
picture_id
url
country_id
```

If some pictures only have a region and not a country, add a `region_id` to `Pictures` and make it nullable along with `country_id`.

To select, just join using the columns with the same names like this:

```
select url
from pictures p
join countries c on p.country_id = c.country_id
join regions r on r.region_id = c.region_id
```

And add a relevant `where` clause:

```
where c.name = 'UK'
```

or

```
where r.name = 'Europe'
```

and so on.

Comment: Are you sure, that the "join" is allowed - shouldn't it be given a type? e.g. inner, left, right?

Comment: Inner is implied if you don't specify something else. I usually don't write it myself but you might have a different style.

Answer (score 0):

This answer makes the following assumptions:

- `regions` and `countries` have the same structure
- `countries` belong to exactly one `region`
- Images are tagged to exactly one `country` or `region`

Using the first assumption that `regions` and `countries` are actually the same we'd have a table with this `CREATE` statement

```
CREATE TABLE `locations` (
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `type` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', -- This will be 'region' or 'country'
    `parent_id` INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL
    -- Insert your other fields here...
);
```

And then we'd have the table for `images` with the following

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `file_path` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `location_id` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- This will probably be a country.
    -- Your Other fields here...
);
```

Now to search for an image by `region` OR `country` we just need to pass in the `location_id` to get that specific location.

The important part here is the `parent_id` for the `locations`, we can query with this field to get all countries which are within a region.

If we had a region with `id = 8` we could do the following:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM `locations` AS l
INNER JOIN `images` AS i ON i.location_id = l.id
WHERE l.id = 8
OR l.parent_id = 8
```

Then this would give us any images which are attached directly to region 8, or to a country which is part of region 8.

For a country we could do the exact same search but assuming `countries` are attached directly to `regions` we would only get images attached to that country, giving us the correct results, but you could of course add an `AND l.type = 'region'` if you wanted to.

Hopefully my answer is clear enough.

Comment: Well this gives him a problem if he needs to get the regions returned even though there is no images - the inner join will block that. I would recommend a RIGHT JOIN in this case - and maybe a count on the row from images like count(i.id) as img_count to later on check if anything was returned :)

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to introduce a tree hierarchy into the schema here. A region and a country are likely to represent to very different real-world things.

Comment: @denlau You're absolutely right if you need to get the location details even when there are no tagged images, but it's a simple enough change. :)

Comment: @MikeBrant Possibly, but I've built similar systems before and never had this issue, but it is outlined as one of the assumptions made in the solution.